# Possible to paginate on single.php?

Tags: pagination, single

I know this sounds illogical and maybe it is, but the client's asked for it so I'm looking into a solution if possible.

On a section of the site there's a link that leads to category-news.php, which displays all posts belonging to News. The user loads each of these posts dynamically through the use of InfiniteScroll, with the posts being paginated beforehand.

The client has requested to also want this feature when viewing a single post item of the same category (i.e. "View more"). I can't seem to create a pagination for single.php, and would like to know if this is even possible to begin with? What happens now is that I get only 1 additional post beyond the current.

Here's the code for single.php so far -

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php $currentID = get_the_ID(); ?>
<article>
  <section>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(466,9999) ) ?>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
    <h6><?php the_date() ?></h6>
    <div class="share"><span class='st_sharethis_custom'>Share</span></div>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </section>
</article>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<?php
$paged = get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
$news = new WP_Query( array('cat' => 3, 'paged' => $paged, 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post__not_in' => array($currentID), 'orderby' => 'date', 'order' => 'DESC') );
while ($news->have_posts()) : $news->the_post();
?>
<article>
  <section>
    <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(466,9999) ) ?>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h1><?php the_title() ?></h1>
    <h6><?php the_date() ?></h6>
    <div class="share"><span class='st_sharethis_custom'>Share</span></div>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
  </section>
</article>
<?php endwhile; endif; ?>
<div class="infiniteScroll"><?php next_posts_link('') ?></div>
```

(Running the current post first, then adding a WP Query to retrieve the rest.)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest implementation would be to put your infinite scroll in `category.php`, and then, either using `Dashboard -> Settings -> Reading -> Posts per page`, or via direct query modification, display one post per page.

Otherwise, depending on how you're implementing the infinite scroll, you could make use of [`next_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link) and [`previous_post_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link), both of which have an `$in_same_cat` parameter.

Comment: All these things you mention is exactly what I'm currently doing :) My question is whether it's possible to implement pagination on single.php.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand? `previous_post_link()` and `next_post_link()` are used to implement previous/next post links on single blog posts. Do you mean [1][2][3] type pagination links?

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I was unclear about the pagination. Right now I'm using the next_post_link() under category-news.php, which is then replaced by the InfiniteScroll function (whereas the URL would otherwise be "/news/page/2"). The same would go for this single.php if possible.

Comment: Just to make sure: in `category-news.php`, do you have `next_post_link()` or `next_posts_link()`? (Note: `post` vs **`posts`**)

Comment: In category-news.php I'm using next_posts_link() and it works fine. I tried the post without s alternative on single.php but it gave no result - still only showing 1 post after the current.
I guess what I want to achieve here is - even if it sounds weird - "news/a-sample-post/page/2". So that when the user lands on a single post (a-sample-post) they are able to continue skimming through the posts on that very page for the category News.

Comment: I think that might confuse WordPress, since Posts themselves can be paginated? But, infinite scrolling is well-outside my area of expertise, so hopefully someone else will shed some light on things...

Comment: Yeah, I guess this won't work very well with WP. It would probably be better to instead avoid using single.php and, in some way, redirecting all single posts to the category-news.php, where that post gets on top of the "list". Not building any archive feature here so this structure shouldn't pose a problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
//redirect single
add_filter('redirect_canonical','pif_disable_redirect_canonical');

function pif_disable_redirect_canonical($redirect_url) {
if (is_single()) $redirect_url = false;
return $redirect_url;
}
```

I found something similar on wp forum, then you add the js or whatever custom loop that support pagination in single.php

Comment: Link to the source of the code please.

Comment: I put this code to my functions.php and it works. I have an ajax-pagination on a single.php.